# How to use method showMessage()?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

In class we learned about methods, but I'm having a bit of trouble using them.

In a package called util, I wrote a class called IO.

```
public class IO {

    public static float getFloat(){
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a real number");
        return Float.parseFloat(str);
    }

    public static void showMessage(Scanner s){
        System.out.println(s);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
    }

    public static Scanner getInput (String prompt){
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return new Scanner(s);
    }

}
```

Also in package util, I have my program, called Program 4.

```
public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IO.getInput("enter 2 integers");
        IO.showMessage(Scanner(s));    
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how do I display the 2 integers entered? One is a scanner object and one is string. How do I use the method getInput to show convert the scanner into a string? Am I going to have to write a new method and use parse?

Comment: In sincerity, I think you should contact your instructor.

Comment: or view some other code like http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html

Comment: My OP may have been a little badly worded, and I don't think I really explained what I needed. A better question would be: say I took out the line right after " IO.getInput("enter 2 integers"); " When I do that, my program runs and lets me input 2 integers. What I want to know now is where is that input stored? And how do I access where it is stored so I can display the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can get user input without using `Scanner`. Here is example:

**IO Class**

```
public class IO {

    public static float getFloat() {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a real number");
        return Float.parseFloat(str);
    }

    public static void showMessage(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
    }

    public static String getInput(String prompt) {
        // JOptionPane.showInputDialog() return user input String
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return input;
    }

}
```

**Program4 Class**

```
public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // IO.getInput() return stored input String
        String input = IO.getInput("enter 2 integers");
        IO.showMessage(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for you taking your time to write that, but my instructor would like for us to use those methods in the IO class in my original post.   A better question would be: say I took out the line right after "     IO.getInput("enter 2 integers");      "  When I do that, my program runs and lets me input 2 integers. What I want to know now is where is that input stored? And how do I access where it is stored so I can display the data?